# Extract specific data to multiple file in different directorty

Tags: text-processing

I would like to do something quite complex, but I will try to explain as simply as possible.
I have many directories on my Linux machine with different names, but they all have the same format (e.g. `1trg_A -> ????_?`) and within each folder I have one or more files called in the same way (the reference codes vary between them and are linked to the name of the folder: ex. `Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt`). So within each folder `????_?` I have one or more files called `Pocket_***_????_?.pdb_OUTPUT.txt`
Each of these files is as follows:

```
input PDB-File:         /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/1trg_A/1b47_A.pdb
Pocket File:            /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/1trg_A/Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb
Pocket Surface:         460.7  
Hydrophobic Surface:    54.6    (11.8%)
Polar Surface:          291.4   (63.2%)
Acceptor Surface:       226.7   (49.2%)
Donnor Surface:         163.7   (35.5%)
Exposed To Solvent:     133.3   (28.9%)
Pocket Volume:          1044.6 
Hydrophobic Volume:     11.0    ( 1.1%)
Hydrophilic Volume:     199.1   (19.1%)
Flexible Volume:        203.3   (19.5%)
Rigid Volume:           51.9    ( 5.0%)
Buried Volume(B):       32.5    ( 3.1%)
Buried Volume(A):       0.0     ( 0.0%)
```

For each of these directory I would like to extract from each file the name of the pocket (e.g. `Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb`) and the value of the "Exposed to solvent" (Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb  133.3  28.9%).

This operation must be done for each file and put all the data in an output file. For example, we assume that we only have two different directories (`2ert_B` and `6yus_1` ) in which there are two different files (`Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb_OUTPUT.txt` and `Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb_OUTPUT.txt`).

Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb_OUTPUT.txt:

```
input PDB-File:         /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/2ert_B/2ert_B.pdb
Pocket File:            /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/2ert_B/Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb
Pocket Surface:         460.7  
Hydrophobic Surface:    54.6    (11.8%)
Polar Surface:          291.4   (63.2%)
Acceptor Surface:       226.7   (49.2%)
Donnor Surface:         163.7   (35.5%)
Exposed To Solvent:     125.4   (49.9%)
Pocket Volume:          1044.6 
Hydrophobic Volume:     11.0    ( 1.1%)
Hydrophilic Volume:     199.1   (19.1%)
Flexible Volume:        203.3   (19.5%)
Rigid Volume:           51.9    ( 5.0%)
Buried Volume(B):       32.5    ( 3.1%)
Buried Volume(A):       0.0     ( 0.0%)
```

Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb_OUTPUT.txt:

```
input PDB-File:         /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/6yus_1/26yus_1.pdb
Pocket File:            /home/tommaso/Desktop/E3-ligase/CHAINS-approach/chains/6yus_1/Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb
Pocket Surface:         460.7  
Hydrophobic Surface:    54.6    (11.8%)
Polar Surface:          291.4   (63.2%)
Acceptor Surface:       226.7   (49.2%)
Donnor Surface:         163.7   (35.5%)
Exposed To Solvent:     45.3   (22.4%)
Pocket Volume:          1044.6 
Hydrophobic Volume:     11.0    ( 1.1%)
Hydrophilic Volume:     199.1   (19.1%)
Flexible Volume:        203.3   (19.5%)
Rigid Volume:           51.9    ( 5.0%)
Buried Volume(B):       32.5    ( 3.1%)
Buried Volume(A):       0.0     ( 0.0%)
```

The file "output.txt" would be like this:

```
Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb 125.4   49.9%
Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb 45.3   22.4%
```

I have no idea how to do this, I hope it was clear and that there is someone more experienced than me who can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please add code formatting, your Q is quite unreadable as is...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working in bash, with gnu grep and sed and with your 3 directories:

```
$ ls
1trg_A  2ert_B  6yus_1
```

You can use the globstar feature (**) in bash

```
$ ls **/Pocket_*.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
1trg_A/Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt  2ert_B/Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb_OUTPUT.txt  6yus_1/Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
```

So now, all you need to do is find the lines you want with grep

```
$ grep -e '^Exposed To Solvent:' **/Pocket_*.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
1trg_A/Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt:Exposed To Solvent:     133.3   (28.9%)
2ert_B/Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb_OUTPUT.txt:Exposed To Solvent:     125.4   (49.9%)
6yus_1/Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb_OUTPUT.txt:Exposed To Solvent:     45.3   (22.4%)
```

Then you have to use sed to modify the extracted lines. The complet command looks like

```
$ grep -e '^Exposed To Solvent:' **/Pocket_*.pdb_OUTPUT.txt | sed -e 's/^.*\(Pocket.*\.pdb\).*:/\1/;s/[()]//g' >myfile
$ cat myfile
Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb     133.3   28.9%
Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb     125.4   49.9%
Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb     45.3   22.4%
```

note: I assumed there was no file Pocket_001_1trg_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt in a 2ert_B folder.

Answer (score 0):

I automatically reached for `find` and `awk` in this

```
find . -type f -name "Pocket*.pdb" -exec awk -F: '$1~"Solvent"{last = split(FILENAME, bits, "/"); print bits[last],$2}' {} \;

Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb      45.3   (22.4%)
Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb      125.4   (49.9%)
```

**Walkthrough**

From `.` `find` all files `-type f` whose `-name` matches the pattern `"Pocket*.pdb"` and `-exec`ute the following code

```
find . -type f -name "Pocket*.pdb" -exec
```

`awk` through each file (line by line) using a `-F`ield separator of `:` doing nothing until you find the text you are interested in `$1~"Solvent"`

```
  awk -F: '$1~"Solvent"{
```

Once you find a match `split` the `FILENAME` into `bits[]` on `/` storing the number of bits it was chopped up into as `last`, then `print` the file name (which is in `bits[last]`) together with the data you want which is in `$2`, Then `exit` as don't need to process further. Do this `awk` individually for each file `{}` found individually `\;`

```
    last = split(FILENAME, bits, "/"); print bits[last],$2; exit 1}' {} \;
```

**But after all that typing** @renaud `globstar` works just as well with the `awk`

```
awk -F: '$1~"Solvent"{last = split(FILENAME, bits, "/"); print bits[last],$2; exit 1}' **/Pocket*.pdb

Pocket_001_2ert_B.pdb      125.4   (49.9%)
Pocket_003_6yus_1.pdb      45.3   (22.4%)
```

Just a different order.